# cannot start cassandra. Fail setting ulimit

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I installed cassandra and tried starting service but stuck with below error. May I know What value I should change? Thanks for your time.

```
#service dse start
Starting DSE daemon : dse
DSE daemon starting with just Cassandra enabled (edit /etc/default/dse to enable)
Fail setting `ulimit '-p' '8'`: /etc/init.d/dse: line 430: ulimit: pipe size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

 /etc/init.d/dse file contains below info

copy_limits(){
    # Use CASSANDRA_USER as a default argument
    local user=${1:-${CASSANDRA_USER}}

    # Since /bin/sh has a limited `ulimit` and `prlimit` from 'utils-linux' is
    #   not well spread, we use `for` as an alternative
    local c
    for p in -t -f -d -s -c -m -l -p -n; do
        local v="$( su - "$user" -s /bin/sh -c "ulimit $p" 2>/dev/null )"
==>line 430 in error ***** :       ulimit $p $v 2>&1 | \
            while read err; do
                log_message "Fail setting \`ulimit '$p' '$v'\`: $err"
            done
    done
}
```

Comment: have you reviewed [this doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html) especially the portion about user limits? The recommended settings are: "Packaged installs: Ensure that the following settings are included in the /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf file:

cassandra - memlock unlimited
cassandra - nofile 100000
cassandra - nproc 32768
cassandra - as unlimited"

Comment: hi, yes, I checked them and found they are present in the file. Still when I start I get this error. Any help where else I need to fix the settings? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node should be **UP** regardless of the error message. You can verify this by running `sudo service dse status` or `nodetool ring`.

If that does not help, a workaround would be to edit **/etc/init.d/dse** and remove the `-p` flag in the for loop that you're seeing in the error message (`for p in -t -f -d -s -c -m -l -n; do`)

Comment: removing the -p flag worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Could you also share little information on what trouble it was causing and how removing it effect? Thanks again I was stuck with it for long time.

Comment: The error message `Fail setting ulimit '-p' '8': /etc/init.d/dse: line 430: ulimit: pipe size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument` is saying that the OS you're using is not supporting `ulimit -p`, so removing it from the script solved the issue for you. That issue should also be fixed in the next DSE patch release.